# Where Is Laravel Forge Scheduler In The Server?

Tags: cron

A scheduler is set through Forge but running `crontab -e` in the server (Ubuntu 16.04) outputs `no crontab for forge - using an empty one` and then opens an empty default file. Where is it being set? The `user` is the same i.e., `forge` in this case.

[image]

Comment: Maybe take a look in `/etc/crontab` or something similar?

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz. Everything was included in `/etc/crontab` but why does `crontab -e` behave like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are a couple ways `cron` tasks can be configured, in various locations. Looks like Forge puts its tasks in `/etc/crontab`, which won't be visible/editable with `crontab -l` or `crontab -e`.